# Grid View bound to SqlDataSource creating paging trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

I am developing a web app using C#, .net 4. I have a grid view which is bound to a SqlDataSource. There are about more than one crore records of this data source. This is because, I have allowed paging. I have a filter criteria on the same page. User selects options using checkboxes. And then on the event of filter Button, I wrote some code which builds a new SELECT command according to the filter options for SqlDataSource. And after building a new query. I wrote another line of code which is:

DataGridView.SelectCommand= FilteredQuery;

So when user clicks FilterButton, the gridview shows the filtered data. As i told you, I have allowed Paging. So after filteration, when i selects the next button of that gridview, it shows the whole data instead of Filtered one. I think this is because it postsbacks the page and binds the  gridview according to the predefined SELECT command for SqlDataSource.

I tried many approaches. I used static bool variable to keep track on page_load event. It works fine then. But it still troubles when i nevigate from one page to another. When i come back to this page, it still shows the filtered data.

I have very less time. Please guide me as soon as possible. Remember, I'm totally new to dot net technologies. So any detailed guidance will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create OnPageIndex Changed event

```
<asp:GridView ID="yourGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanged="yourGrid_PageIndexChanged">
```

And in code behind

```
protected void yourGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (filtered) // you would have to keep track of the filtered state of your grid possibly with hidden field
    {
        DataGridView.SelectCommand = FilteredQuery;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well..but it does not help. May be my logic is wrong. Let me share my code and check if you can fix it. Here it is:

Where i can share my code with you?
May i have ur email address??

Comment: Thank you so much friend..:)
I am done with it..I used Page_Unload method..
when user navigates to other page..my FLAG variables sets to false..
And if its false..my page shows the full data..it would be true only when user will click the filter problem..SO solved :)

Answer (score 0):

SQLDATASOURCE wont work this way. On every page change, you need to recreate your sql query. Try skipping certain rows on each page change.

Here is an example for you.

**FOR PAGE - 1**

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YOURKEY desc) AS rownumber,
    *
  FROM YOURTABLE
) AS ANYTHING
WHERE rownumber >= STARTING ROW and rownumber <= ENDINGROW
```

---

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
 SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bowzer_id desc) AS rownumber,
        *
      FROM Bowzer
    ) AS BowzerTable
    WHERE rownumber >= 10 and rownumber <= 20
```

**FOR PAGE  - 2**

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bowzer_id desc) AS rownumber,
    *
  FROM Bowzer
) AS BowzerTable
WHERE rownumber >= 20 and rownumber <= 30
```

**For PAGE - 3**

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bowzer_id desc) AS rownumber,
    *
  FROM Bowzer
) AS BowzerTable
WHERE rownumber >= 30 and rownumber <= 40
```

You need to recreate your SQL query on every page change, as shown in example above.